# How to Solve Dropbox {“error”: “v1_retired”} for the Dropbox API

Tags: php, dropbox

Dropbox shut down the version 1 of their API on September 28th 2017 in favor of the new Dropbox API v2 which causes the error {“error”: “v1_retired”}. This step was already announced in June 2016 and all developers were notified about it and received several errors and notifications. As of September 28th 2017 all requests to the old API return HTTP status 400 {“error”: “v1_retired”}.
How do I solve {“error”: “v1_retired”}? Thanks you

Comment: You start calling the V2 api endpoints "_On this date, API v1 endpoints will return a 400 error with this message: {“error”: “v1_retired”}. This means any integrations or applications still relying on API v1 endpoints may stop working._" https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/

Comment: So there is a reasonable solution?

Comment: You have to refactor your application adhering to their guidelines.

Comment: The documentation for using API v2 can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox migration from V1 to V2

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide

If code uses the V1 version of accessing objects then it will result in
{"error": "v1_retired" }

with the exception

com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadRequest: 
{
"error": "v1_retired"
}
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.unexpectedStatus(DbxRequestUtil.java:202)

at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$2.handle(DbxClient.java:181)

at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.doGet(DbxRequestUtil.java:265
...